# Setting min and max for chart in Highcharts library error

Tags: highcharts

Please take a look at my code in JSFiddle;

```
const chart = { title: { text: "" }, exporting: { enabled: false }, series: [], xAxis: [ { min: 0, max: 10, legend: { enabled: true } } ],
yAxis: [] };
const yAxis = { id: 0, title: { text: "test" }, min: 1, max: 100 }
chart.yAxis.push( yAxis );
const series = { type: "line", id: 0, data: [], name: "test" }
chart.series.push( series );
Highcharts.stockChart( 'container', chart );
```

[Highchart Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/reza_karimi76/fg92z8o6/23/)

Check console for seeing error.

The problem is in setting "min" and "max" of xAxis. If I remove those two properties, it works fine. Could someone tell me what the problem is. I need to have min and max for my chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` property should be unique and should be a string:

```
const yAxis = {
  id: '0',
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/op4hudwf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.id

Comment: Thanks. Although the error in concole should be more clear than what it is